# How do I remove the square brackets at the end of a JS variable name during AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I currently have the following javascript array:

```
var stuffs = ['a', 'b'];
```

I pass the above to the server code using jQuery's `load`:

```
var data = {
    'stuffs': stuffs
};

$(".output").load("/my-server-code/", data, function() {
});
```

On the server side, if I print the content of `request.POST`(I'm currently using Django), I get:

```
'stuffs[]': [u'a', u'b']
```

Notice the `[]` at the prefix of the variable name `stuffs`.  Is there a way to remove that `[]` before it reaches the server code?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is default behavior [in jQuery 1.4+](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14)...if you want the post to be `&stuffs=a&stuffs=b` instead of `&stuffs[]=a&stuffs[]=b` you should set the  [`traditional` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `true`, like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({traditional: true});
```

Note this affects all requests... which is usually what you want in this case.  If you want it to be *per-request* you should use the longer [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) call and set `traditional: true` there.  [You can find more info about `traditional` in the `$.param()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Comment: In 1.10 $.ajaxSettings is not callable - $.ajaxSetup should be used instead - its usage is the same as above.

Answer (score -1):

When an array is submitted using a GET request, through a form or AJAX, each element is given the name of the array, followed by a pair of optionally empty square brackets. So the jQuery is generating the url  `http://example.com/get.php?stuff[]=a&stuff[]=b`. This is the only way of submitting an array, and the javascript is following the standard.

`POST` requests work in exactly the same way (unless the json is sent as one long json string).

In PHP, this is parsed back into the original array, so although the query string can be a little strange, the data is recieved as it was sent. `$_GET['stuff'][0]` works correctly in PHP.

I'm not sure how Django parses query strings.

Comment: "This is the only way of submitting an array, and the javascript is following the standard." - It's *not* a standard but Rails/PHP convention. Arrays can be perfectly legally sent as foo=1&foo=2.

Answer (score -3):

The `[]` indicates that the variable is an array. I imagine that the appending of the `[]` to your variable name is Python/Django's way of telling you it is an array. You could probably implement your own print function which does not show them.

Comment: Does that mean the appending of [] is coming from Django instead of javascript?